# Newbie: Placing a link and a image on CSS code is not working

Tags: css

I am having a problem setting the right place to one link in my css code:
The link is a text "hide" placed on the upper right corner on the footer banner of this website: http://iknowfirst.com
I want to place a little bit lower

The specific css code is here: http://iknowfirst.com/wp-content/plugins/yith-footer-banner/assets/css/style.css

Besides that, I cannot see the image: "images/mailwhite.png" that is set to show on the email field.

Someone can give me a light?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the text "hide" inside ul.hiderzone - you need to decrease margin-bottom for the ul.

About css:
css path is:
http://iknowfirst.com/wp-content/plugins/yith-footer-banner/assets/css/style.css
path to image written as

```
url(../images/mailwhite.png)
```

so, real image path is:
http://iknowfirst.com/wp-content/plugins/yith-footer-banner/assets/images/mailwhite.png

UPD: you copy css rules into page body, so fix line 266.
Instead:

```
background-image: url("../images/mailwhite.png");
```

place:

```
background-image: url("/wp-content/plugins/yith-footer-banner/assets/images/mailwhite.png");
```

Comment: Just another question, how can I take out the white border of the box that contain the form and the submit button?

Comment: This is a fieldset border. Add a new rule: `.fbannernewsletter fieldset {border: 0;}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your 2 issues

1) Placing a link
Solution : in your CSS

```
.hiderzone {
right: 10px;
top: -12px; /*Edit this, this will help you*/
bottom: 2px;
/*top: auto;*/ /*You should not use "TOP" twice */
list-style: none; }
```

2) You can use relative or absolute image path

Relative Path
    background-image: url("../images/mailwhite.png");

Absolute Path
    background-image: url("/wp-content/plugins/yith-footer-banner/assets/images/mailwhite.png");